# Telerik Controls inclusion in Visual Studio 2013 for windows desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2013, telerik

Now only i installed visual studio 2013 for windows desktop to create some applications. i don't know how to include the third party control (Telerik Controls) into it. So help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to add the control in the toolbox

**Using the Visual Studio menus**

1. Run Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010/2012/2013.
2. Open any windows forms project/solution.
3. Expand the Toolbox.
4. Right-click the Toolbox in the empty area underneath and choose Add Tab to create a new tab. Name the tab " Telerik UI for WinForms ".
5. Open a Windows Explorer and locate the Telerik assemblies folder.
6. Select the following assemblies and drag-drop them to the empty space in the newly created tab in Visual Studio:
   Telerik.WinControls.RichTextBox.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.SpellChecker.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.GridView.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.RadChart.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.RadDock.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.RadMarkupEditor.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Scheduler.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Aqua.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Breeze.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Desert.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.HighContrastBlack.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2007Black.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2007Silver.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2010Black.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2010Blue.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Office2010Silver.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.TelerikMetro.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.Themes.Windows7.dll
   Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll

Note for point 5:

> If you have installed the controls with the default settings then it
>   would be this directory: "C:\Program Files\Telerik\UI for
>   WinForms\Version\Bin" for most the .NET2.0 version of our assemblies
>   and "C:\Program Files\Telerik\UI for WinForms\Version\Bin40" for the
>   .NET4.0 version of the assemblies (note that currently RadRichTextBox
>   and RadSpellChecker are only available in the .NET4.0 version).

**References** -
[Adding RadControls to Visual Studio Toolbox](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/installation-deployment-and-distribution-adding-radcontrols-to-visual-studio-toolbox.html)
[Manually add RadControls for WinForms to the VS Toolbox](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/manually-add-radcontrols-for-winforms-to-the-vs-toolbox)
[All Rad controls gone from Toolbox!](http://www.telerik.com/forums/all-rad-controls-gone-from-toolbox)